# Remove part of string after 3-digit number

Tags: r, gsub

I would like to substitute the strings in the list by cutting each string after the first 3-digit number.

```
a <- c("MTH314PHY410","LB471LB472","PHY472CHM141")
```

I would like for it to look something like

```
a <- c("MTH314","LB471","PHY472")
```

I have tried something like

```
b <- gsub("[100-999].*","",a)
```

but it returns `c("MTH","LB","PHY")` without the first number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution, based on `stringr::str_remove`:

```r
library(stringr)

a <- c("MTH314PHY410","LB471LB472","PHY472CHM141")

str_remove(a, "(?<=\\d{3}).*")

#> [1] "MTH314" "LB471"  "PHY472"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
c("MTH314PHY410","LB471LB472","PHY472CHM141") %>% 
    stringr::str_extract('.+?\\d{3}')
```

```
[1] "MTH314" "LB471"  "PHY472"
```